# How to level div boxes in css?

Tags: css, html, line

Please look at this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/eJTGr/

If you minimize the 'Javascript' area so the 'Result' area is enlarged you will see that it is two white boxes with a grey border next to eachother with a black box at the end that is slightly out of line.

How is this put in line with the two white boxes?

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 3):

You can set the position of .button1 to relative and add a top attribute. Doing this will allow you to move the button down a couple pixels — 6px in your case.

Your .button1 class would be

```
.button1 {
    height: 35px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #151515;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color: #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
    horizontal-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:bottom` to the `.button1` class.

```
.button1 {
 height: 35px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #151515;
    border:1px solid;
    border-color: #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
    horizontal-align: center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Reason : Your `divs` are defined as `inline-block`. Consider them like table rows. Sometime they do not take the same vertical alignment.

Note :
**.search-field1** got a `verticle-align: center;` while **.search-field2** got a `horizontal-align: center;`, which I think, does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

just give the Button

```
position: absolute;
```

but this isn't the best way i would do something like

```
.form-container {
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    }
.form-element {
    float: left;
    }

</style>

<div class="form-container">
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="text/plain"

    <div class="form-element"><input type="text" name="" /></div>
    <div class="form-element"><input type="text" name="" /></div>
    <div class="form-element"><input type="submit" name="" /></div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `display-inline` from the tags. Then add `float:left` to each. Remove `vertical-align: 9px;` from the inputs. I also removed the `margin-top:4px` from the button1 Note: the center tag has been deprecated so don't use for your websites.

[Check out demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eJTGr/27/)

Comment: Thanks! but it still is to the left? How do I get it in the center?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" />
```

instead of

```
<div class="button1" style="margin-top:4px;"></div>
```

Clean code : http://jsfiddle.net/eJTGr/30/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="search-field1">
        <input type="text" name="search1" />
    </div>

    <div id="search-field2">
        <input type="text" name="search2" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper { text-align: center; }

#search-field1 {
    height: 35px;
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
}

#search-field2 {
    height: 35px;
    width: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    height: 36px;
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"] {
    height: 35px;
    width: 320px; 
    border:0px; 
}
```